# Bucket Sort on non-numeric (keyword) field

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I have index with products, each product has `category` and `category_owner`. I'd like to show on my GUI table with all categories sorted by category_owner, but table must be pageable.

I know there is a way to sort (and paging) aggregations using `bucket_sort`. Example

```
GET products/_search
{
  "size": 0, 
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "aggs": {
    "unique_categories": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "category",
        "size": 1000
      },
      "aggs": {
        "inner": {
          "avg": {
            "field": "price"
          }
        },
        "soring_agg": {
          "bucket_sort": {
            "sort": [
              {
                "inner": {"order": "asc"}
              }
            ],
            "from": 1,
            "size": 1
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But is there any way to sort on the non-number field? I can create `term` aggregation with size 1 or `top_hists` search, for example

```
      "aggs": {
        "inner": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 1,
            "sort": [
              {
                "@timestamp": {"order": "desc"}
              }
            ],
            "_source": {
              "includes": ["category_owner"]
            }
          }
        },
        "soring_agg": {
          "bucket_sort": {
            "sort": [
              {
                "inner": {"order": "asc"}
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
```

Bu I've got the error `buckets_path must reference either a number value or a single value numeric metric aggregation, got: [InternalTopHits] at aggregation [inner]`

`terms` aggregation also does not works

```
        "inner": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "category_owner",
            "size": 1
          }
        },
```

`buckets_path must reference either a number value or a single value numeric metric aggregation, got: [StringTerms] at aggregation [inner]`

Is there a way to create pagination on unique categories sorted by owner?

EDIT:
I can create all uniqe categories for each owner but I have to sort and paging it manually in my app :(

```
  "aggs": {
    "owners": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "category_owner",
        "size": 100000
      },
      "aggs": {
        "categories": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "category",
            "size": 1000
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: From docs:   bucket sort only applies to whatever buckets are already returned from the parent aggregation. For example, if the parent aggregation is terms and its size is set to 10, the bucket_sort will only sort over those 10 returned term buckets. So if you are looking for paging in terms aggregation you need to either use composite aggrgetaion or incluse partiions

Comment: But I can set size = 100000 in parent agg ant its good enough